# I am not able to install mongodb driver in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am trying to install mongodb driver in Visual Studio 2012 ultimate using nuget package manager, But always getting error : 'DnsClient' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Buffers'. What shall I do?